# How to notify all users?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I prepared a notification app.

I would like to send a notification to all users.
If I use this line:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

[image: As at image]

it creates me a possibility to send a notification to the user which I need to choose. I would like to have an option to send a notification to all of users in the same time

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Notifications(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tytul")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Wiadomosci")
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Otwarta")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from models import Notifications

def show_notification(request, notification_id):
    n = Notifications.objects.get(id=notification_id)
    return render_to_response('notifications.html',{'notification':n})

def delete_notification(request, notification_id):
    n = Notifications.objects.get(id=notification_id)
    n.viewed = True
    n.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
```

Comment: So... what's the question? How to add a Notification object for each user?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all users and create notification for each of them:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
  for user in User.objects.all():
      Notifications.objects.create(title="some title", content="some content",
                                   user=user)
```

As side note: you have a security problem in `show_notification()` and `delete_notification()`.  You show/delete notification to/by any visitor.  Add filter by user like this:

```
@login_required
def show_notification(request, notification_id):
    n = Notifications.objects.get(id=notification_id, user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: It is not exatcly what I need. Could you take a look please on my print screen which I attached

Answer (score 0):

To add a Notification for each User, here's a solution:

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    [...]
    @classmethod
    def notify_all(klass, title, content):
        new_notices = list()
        for u in User.objects.all():
            new_notices.append(klass(user=u, title=title, content=content))
        klass.objects.bulk_create(new_notices)
```

Then, to run this you do:

```
Notification.notify_all('Test title', 'Test message')
```

Comment: Thank you :) but where should I add this line? Notification.notify_all('Test title', 'Test message')

Comment: @user3904216 You'd call that last line in whatever code triggers the notification. It could be a view, it could even be in another model's code. It depends entirely on how and when you want to create these notifications.

Comment: @user3904216 Now I see the screen cap you added. If you want to do this through the admin, you'll want to add some kind of checkbox to your ModelAdmin form or maybe push an "all" choice into your user select widget. Then you check for this "all" signal and short-circuit the normal admin save and run your notify_all instead. Docs on customizing ModelAdmin and related forms are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: you can specify your own ModelForm for admin model and add one extra field. Then in customized save method of form you should check if this field is True or False (if you will be using checkbox) and send notification to all users or just create one notification. Using ``transaction.atomic()`` as in answer by @catavaran is recomended